# How to extract data from mapdataset tensorflow in python

Tags: python, tensorflow

I try to do data preparation by dividing my dataset into time window. The user definition function was created by following code.

```
class WindowGenerator_with_nan():
    def __init__(self, input_width, label_width, shift, x_iter,
           train_df=cluster_concat_train_df, val_df=cluster_concat_val_df, 
           test_df=cluster_concat_test_df,
           label_columns=None):
     # Store the raw data.
     self.train_df = cluster_concat_train_df[x_iter]
     self.val_df = cluster_concat_val_df[x_iter]
     self.test_df = cluster_concat_test_df[x_iter]

     # Work out the label column indices.
     self.label_columns = label_columns
     if label_columns is not None:
     self.label_columns_indices = {name: i for i, name in
                                enumerate(label_columns)}
     self.column_indices = {name: i for i, name in
                       enumerate(train_df[x_iter].columns)}

     # Work out the window parameters.
     self.input_width = input_width
     self.label_width = label_width
     self.shift = shift

     self.total_window_size = input_width + shift

     self.input_slice = slice(0, input_width)
     self.input_indices = np.arange(self.total_window_size)[self.input_slice]

     self.label_start = self.total_window_size - self.label_width
     self.labels_slice = slice(self.label_start, None)
     self.label_indices = np.arange(self.total_window_size)[self.labels_slice]

 def __repr__(self):
    return '\n'.join([
    f'Total window size: {self.total_window_size}',
    f'Input indices: {self.input_indices}',
    f'Label indices: {self.label_indices}',
    f'Label column name(s): {self.label_columns}'])
```

In my case, iterated 'i' stand for cluster numbers. However, there are some 'NaN' values were contained after window generators as type "mapdataset"

After I do : `

```
wide_window_with_nan =[WindowGenerator(input_width=96, label_width=1, shift=1, label_columns = ['Labels'], x_iter = i) for i in range(len(df_without_impulate_before_RNN))]
```

Result of this line of code : `print(wide_window_with_nan[0].train)`

```
<MapDataset element_spec=(TensorSpec(shape=(None, 96, 112), dtype=tf.float32, name=None), TensorSpec(shape=(None, 1, 1), dtype=tf.float32, name=None))>
```

My question is how to remove all windows that contain 'NaN' values from mapdata because I have to use this data set to be the input of prediction models. The prediction models do not allow input with NaN values.

P.S. I use google colab pro to be my IDE. Thus, I have to concern about computation resource such as RAM space during execution.

Answer (score 1):

You can remove NaN values by using filter method from the tf.data.Dataset

```
y = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices([np.nan, 0, 1, 2, 3])
filter_nan = lambda y: not tf.math.is_nan(y)
ds = y.filter(filter_nan)
list(ds.as_numpy_iterator())
>>>[0.0, 1.0, 2.0, 3.0]
```

Thank You.